# Https address behaves differently on ios and android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, dio

Currently modding logging logic for client with working Android app to also work on iOS. App is using DIO to make and handle https calls. Addresses are stored in a separate file as strings (lets call it 'settings').

Obviously cannot provide original links but it goes something like this:

```
const String firstUrl = 'https://best-service-ever.com/access/';
const String secondUrl = 'https://another-good-service.com';
```

Currently code looks like this in logging script:

```
static Uri get firstUri => Uri.parse(settings.firstUrl);

  static Uri get loginUri =>
      firstUri.resolve('login').replace(queryParameters: <String, dynamic>{'service': settings.secondUrl});
```

**Android generates good loginUri**- `https://best-service-ever.com/access/login?service=https://another-good-service.com`

But for some miraculous reason on ios loginURI is `https://best-service-ever.com/login?service=https://another-good-service.com`.

Why and how the endpoint would be lost while parsing and only on one platform?

**Also I can't just modify `resolve('access/login')` i need the address in multiple places as is.

**Also I'm currently running Flutter channel stable 2.10.5 on macOS 11.6.5

Answer (score 0):

please try this way

```
const String firstUrl = 'https://best-service-ever.com/access/login';
const String secondUrl = 'https://another-good-service.com';
Uri  loginUri = Uri.parse(
    firstUrl).replace(queryParameters: <String, dynamic>{'service':secondUrl}); 
    print(loginUri);
```

Comment: What about the 'login' parameter? https://best-service-ever.com/**access/login?**service=https://another-good-service.com

Comment: You can check edited answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a bug in flutter. I would then maybe work around it by doing it like this

```
String base = 'https://best-service-ever.com/';
String get firstUrl => '${base}access/';
String secondUrl = 'https://another-good-service.com';

static Uri get firstUri => Uri.parse(settings.firstUrl);
static Uri get base => Uri.parse(settings.base);
static Uri get loginUri =>
    base.resolve('access/login').replace(queryParameters: <String, dynamic>{'service': settings.secondUrl});
```

that way you can still use the original `firstUrl` in the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Uri.parse` try `Uri.https` maybe it helps.
[Check out this official link for more information](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html)

Comment: I made `Uri.https('best-service-ever.com', '/access');`. Also tried with http. Still no progress. Still getting bad address- without 'access' path.

Comment: Also tried to change whole loginUri according to .https() documentation. No luck